# Setting maximum logged in time in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

I searched but could not find a way to set a timeout for the active session.
I'm using Laravel 10 and using the `cookie` session driver since there are multiple servers. I want to control the session time with by 2 factors:

1. A session timeout if the user is inactive for 30 minutes. For this
   I'm setting `SESSION_LIFETIME` in the .env to 30
2. A session timeout of 1 hour irrespective of the user being active or inactive

I do not have any idea if there is any setting to manage the second condition as well or I need to manage it myself by storing the logged in time and checking it on every request.
Any help, hint or idea is appreciated.

Comment: There's no out of the box way for this. You can try various approaches and if you can't get anything to work you can share some code with what you tried. I personally think a good approach would be to override the built-in [`StartSession`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php) middleware where you can check if there is a session id and if there's not you can probably set a "created at" time for the new session id that is created. If the session id already exists you can check said "created at" time

Comment: After searching and asking, I still could not find any default setting so I think implementing it is the only option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any setting so implemented on my own by overriding the `handle()` method of the `Authenticate` middleware class

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $loginTime=new Carbon(Auth::user()?->login_at);
        if($loginTime->addHour()<now())
            return redirect('/logout');
        return parent::handle($request, $next, $guards);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `config/session.php` you can add:

```php
'lifetime' => 30 // determines how long a session will remain active after the last activity.
```

And set the cookie:

```php
'cookie' => [
    'lifetime' => 60 // determines the time the session is active regardless if the user closes the browser or not
```

Comment: Thank you but there is already a key with name 'cookie' in my config/session.php file by default. If I add it the way you mentioned then it gives me an error that the 'cookie' must be a string.